# Run a function when element rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function, for example:

```
function SuperTD(id,str,tooltip) {
  return '<td id="' +id+ '" title="' +tooltip+ '">' +str+ '</td>';
}
```

The `SuperTD` called and concatenated with many elements, and I don't want to change how it works (into generating element without using html string).

And I need to trigger a function when that elements are rendered, for example:

```
function SuperTD(id,str,tooltip) {
  var onwhat = 'onwhat="executeFixedFunction(' + "'" +id+ "'" + ')"';
  return '<td><div id="' +id+ '" title="' +tooltip+ '" ' +onwhat+ '>' +str+ '</div></td>';
}
```

where `executeFixedFunction` is:

```
function executeFixedFunction(id) {
  $('#' + id).uploadFile({
    url:"/file/upload"
  });
}
```

what the correct event to do this? I need to initialize a [file-upload](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php) element everywhere `SuperTD` called

The users still using Firefox 3.5.

**EDIT** more context:

```
GridBuilder.render = function() {
   // return from cache
   var html = '';
   // calls html += SuperTD( ... )
   return html;
}

GridBuilder.renderTo = function(id) {
   $('#'+id).html(this.render());
   // I guess this is where I should initialize the file upload, but still, is there another way?
}
```

Comment: You can use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) but it is very complicated. I suggest you to change your function `SuperTD` to initiliaze the file upload(which makes more sense) than use an observer.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: Alternatively you can add callback parameter to function definition. `function(id, str, tooltip, callback) { callback();}`

Comment: both solution won't work, since the client still use Firefox 3.5, I will edit my question..

Comment: So use a callback as @RuslanasBalčiūnas said. Its a clever solution for this.

Comment: This will not work. You callback will be called before DOM manipulation. You need to call `executeFixedFunction` somewhere else. Show us more context.

Comment: Maybe I got to far, but take a look at a final edit of my answer. There's a full working example. Note additional `<span>` used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are already using jquery i would consider doing it this way:

```
function superTD (id, str, tooltip) {
  return $('<td/>', {
    id: id,
    title: tooltip,
    text: str
  }).uploadFile({
    url: '/your-url'
  })

}
```

Then you can call `appendTo` method on `superTD` to insert it into table row

Answer (score 2):

You can use a setTimeout function to delay the callback function.

```
function SuperTD(id,str,tooltip) {
  var onwhat = 'onwhat="executeFixedFunction(' + "'" +id+ "'" + ')"';
  setTimeout(function(){ executeFixedFunction(id) }, 1000);
  return '<td><div id="' +id+ '" title="' +tooltip+ '" ' +onwhat+ '>' +str+ '</div></td>';
}
```

Comment: This is not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Everything put together with slightly modified Jakubs suggestion. See on [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/mhneHK9gI47y1yJFtMn6).

```
function superTD(id, str, tooltip, callback) {
    var td = $('<td/>', {
        id: id,
        title: tooltip,
        text: str
    });

    var up = $('<span/>'); // <-- this elm will be replaced
    td.append(up);
    $('#container').append(td);

    callback(up, str);
}

function onCreated(elm, fname) {
    elm.uploadFile({
        url: '/url',
        fname: fname
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    superTD(1, 'foo', 'bar', onCreated);
    superTD(2, 'bar', 'foo', onCreated);
});
```